# Why can't I edit iATS Settings?

Tags: civicontribute, iats

I am running Civi 4.7.22 and iatspayments ext 1.6.1. When I try to edit the settings (Admin>Civicontribute>iATS Payment Settings) my edits won't stick. For instance, I try to edit the email address for notification on failed recurring transactions and submit, but when refreshed the page reverts to previous email settings. Same thing with editing the "Never" to "Always" for receipts.

Anyone with same problem, suggested solutions or troubleshooting thoughts?

Comment: Does your IATS user id end in 01 or 80?

Comment: I always recommend to use 01 as your admin accounts; and ensure only 01  (02 03 etc) have refund capabilities; use your 80, 81, 82 etc as website deposit accounts (ensure they have no refund capabilities - contact iATS Customer Service to set that up); that way even if your site gets hacked - or in case of the disgruntled employee scenario - no-one can log into iATSpayments.com and refund your contributions;

Answer (score 1):

Look at your User Role and Access Permissions. Do you have access to CiviCRM: administer payment processors 
Add, Update, or Disable Payment Processors ???

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed all is well in 4.7.25 -> I can edit/save the civicrm/admin/contribute/iatssettings form and all is there on refresh.

I generally recommend updating to 4.7.25 - from a payment processing point of view our test-matrix transactions grid has never been that green;

Comment: Okay. I will try updating to 4.7.25 to see if that resolves the issue.